# How to get the Used space of a SQL MI Instance using Powershell

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I'm trying to get space used by my Azure SQL MI Instance using powershell Get-AzMetric. Not sure of what should I give in the Parameter -MetricName

```html
$StorageAccounts = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances
        FOREACH($StorageAccount in $StorageAccounts){
            $ResourceId = $StorageAccount.ResourceId     
            $Metric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceId -MetricName "Storagespaceused" -WarningAction Ignore          
            $SQLDBSize = ($Metric.Data | Select-Object -First 1).Total/1024/1024/1024
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `storage_space_used_mb` in the Parameter `-MetricName`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftsqlmanagedinstances

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perfect. Yet again thanks a lot @Joy Wang.

```html
$StorageAccounts = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances
        FOREACH($StorageAccount in $StorageAccounts){
            $ResourceId = $StorageAccount.ResourceId
            $Start = (get-date).AddDays(-7)
            $End = get-date         
            $SpaceMetric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceId -MetricName "storage_space_used_mb" -WarningAction Ignore
            $IOMetric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceId -MetricName "io_requests" -StartTime $Start -EndTime $End -WarningAction Ignore
            $CoreMetric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceId -MetricName "virtual_core_count" -WarningAction Ignore

            #Load Variables for SQL Statement.
            $TeamGroupName = $SubscriptionID.TeamGroupsName
            $ServiceName = $SubscriptionID.ServiceName
            $SubscriptionName = $SubscriptionID.SubscriptionName
            $SubID = $SubscriptionID.SubscriptionID
            $StorageAccountName = $StorageAccount.Name
            $StorageType = 'SQL-MI'
            $SQLMISize = ($SpaceMetric.Data | Select-Object -First 1).Average/1024
            $TotalRequests = ($IOMetric.Data | Select-Object -First 1).Average
            $CoreCount = ($CoreMetric.Data | Select-Object -First 1).Average
            $Region = $StorageAccount.Location
            $RefreshedAt = Get-Date
```